# Why does the facebook app open the notifications in the browser?

Tags: facebook

When I use the Facebook app,if I click on a notification (on the notifications tab), the notification will open on the browser and not on app.

Why is this happening? Can I change it somehow?

The phone's software is Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notifications *used* to open within the app, however, as Facebook have added features to the website version, the app has not been kept in step, and instead they now choose to open some notifications on the web (where you'll see their adverts).

If you do go into the app, and use the notifications within that, it will display most content in-app (notable exclusions seem to be comments on videos, even if they were uploaded via the app)

The course for getting this resolved would be to contact the app publisher, or make your feelings known in a review in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an in-app setting to change this, no, you cannot. This behavior is up to the developer.